# Laravel 4: Restful Controller and Layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I set up a resource on Laravel's `routes.php` like this:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

I created the `UsersController`, and set it to use a layout:

```
class UsersController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function index()
    {
         $view = View::make('users.index');
         $this->layout->title = "User Profile"; 
         $this->layout->content = $view;
    }

}
```

And when I access it using `http://localhost/myapp/users/index` I get the error:

`Undefined variable: title`

But if I manually set the route like:

`Route::get('/users/index', array('as' => '/users/index', 'uses' => 'UsersController@index'));`

It works fine.

Any idea why this happens?

EDIT: these are the views

**default.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>{{ $title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/style.default.css') }}" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

{{ $content }}

</body>

</html>
```

**user/index.php**

```
<div>

Some content ...

</div>
```

Comment: Does the error occur in the template or in the controller?

Comment: The error occurs on the template

Comment: Mmh, thats strange. Could you share the code of the layout and user.index template with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is actually with how you're calling your route.

If you check the documentation (http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers), you'll see that there's no route for `/resource/index`. That's going to be parsed as `/resource/{id}` where $id = "index" and is going to be looking for a `show($id)` function.  It knows it's supposed to use the default layout, but since you don't have a show() function which sets the title, no title is passed to the view and it blows up.

I'd be willing to bet that if you just go to `http://localhost/myapp/users`, it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UsersController extends BaseController {

  protected $layout = 'layouts.default';

  public function index()
  {
    $data['title'] = "User Profile";

    $this->layout->content = View::make('users.index')
      ->withData($data);

    return $this->layout->content;          
  }

}
```

Or

```
class UsersController extends BaseController {

  protected $layout = 'layouts.default';

  public function index()
  {
    $title = "User Profile";

    $this->layout->content = View::make('users.index')
      ->withData($title);

    return $this->layout->content;          
  }

}
```

But it's easy to use the $data array. When using this in your view's you can reference it by it's name. So $data['title'] is called with $title.

Comment: It doesn't work, first it throws the error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\View::withData()`, so I changed it to `$this->layout->content = View::make('users.index')->with($data);`, and it worked out, but it only shows me the `users.index` view, not the entire layout. I removed `return $this->layout->content;` and it throws the initial error again.